# Analysing Excel VBA/Macro code

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a tool which will analyse/parse an entire Excel workbook and let us see all the macros, functions, VBA code?

I've been given a large number of Excel spreadsheets to analyse, we need to know what they do and how they do it, with a view to creating documentation, and/or re-writing. In many instances the original developers are gone and the users don't know the detail.

Comment: Ctrl+` (backtick) will toggle between formula display and value display, which may help a little.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd890502%28office.11%29.aspx might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) which can give you some documentation generation abilities.

There's also some examples of how to do this yourself with VBA [here](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/list-vba-procedures-by-vba-module-and-vb-procedure/)

Comment: good answer, but if the question is give tools that "analyse" my VBA, other readers not familiar with MZ tools should note that it does not have static code analysis capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Additional resources for this question.

For office 2010 you can now use a VBA inspection tool that will alert you to upgrading issues such as deprecated Object model calls, Win32 calls, ActiveX controls that may/will require code changes.
Doesn't provide a complete output of all method and class names. So its not useful for commenting your entire code base, but it does provide useful upgrading comments.

[Remediation Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819096.aspx)

[Code compatibility Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee833946.aspx)